# How to prevent awesomplete from breaking the layout

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

It seems that [awesomplete](https://github.com/LeaVerou/awesomplete) (a nice javascript library for autocomplete functionalty) adds a `div` when the javascript executes during loading the HTML page, thus breaking the layout and moving the label further down because the label "Session Id" is then outside the div:

[image]

How can I avoid this?

The full sample is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/awesomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/awesomplete.css">
</head>
<body>

<label>Fuzziness: </label>
<input name="fuzziness" id="fuzziness" style="width:250px;" type="text">
<br>
<label for="visitId">Session Id: </label>
<input name="visitId" id="visitId" style="width:250px;" class="awesomplete" data-list="Ada, Java, JavaScript, Brainfuck, LOLCODE, Node.js, Ruby on Rails" type="text">
<br>
<label for="visitorId">User Id: </label>
<input name="visitorId" id="visitorId" style="width:250px;" type="text">
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

The actually rendered HTML is

```
<label for="visitId">Session Id: </label>
<div class="awesomplete">
<input id="visitId" class="awesomplete" type="text" data-list="Ada, Java, JavaScript, Brainfuck, LOLCODE, Node.js, Ruby on Rails" style="width:250px;" name="visitId" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list">
...
</div>
```

Comment: So your inputs were in single lines, right?, or which it broke your view?

Comment: This div is added by autocomplete library, so if you are going to this then it is going to use that div, So you need to provide specific CSS to that added div to achieve what you want to achieve... so do let me know what is the issue then I can help you out

Comment: Look at the vertical alignment of the labels to the input fields. The label "Session Id:" is moved down and not properly aligned with the input field any more. I would like to have it at similar height as the other labels to their input fields.

Comment: okay looking into the issue, will get back to you

Comment: I have solved your doubt please look at the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `vertical-align: top` to the Session Id: label element

i.e.

```
<label for="visitId" style="vertical-align: top;">Session Id: </label>
```

And another cleaner solution will be apply `vertical-align: middle` to the both elements i.e. label and autocomplete div

```
<style>
  div.awesomplete {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;// This needs to be added
  }
</style>

<label for="visitId" style="vertical-align: middle;">Session Id: </label>
```

Comment: Thanks. "top" worked somewhat better in my case, still not 100% nicely aligned when there are other elements without the "div", but still fairly ok for my use-case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to run inspector tool in your browser to check .awesomplete style definition and override it.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, in the meantime I found a workaround by adding the following style-definition to the label: `style="position:relative;top:-5px"`, not very nice but it seems to work in my case.